# Jquery DataTable Script Loaded but Not Available On Browser DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I have referenced jqyery dataTabes and JS. 
The results hows that call went ere but will im unable to find DataTable there and shows it as result.

```
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.8/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.8/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.8/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

In Browser : 
although the JS / CSS loads
[image]

But still it doenst exist on DOM , so when i try to apply it to any element it doesnt apply.

[image]

So what is the error why its not being applying in DOM of browser or from code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was the jquery reference , i was referencing to jquery 2.1.1 and 2.1.4 version of jQuery. removing 2.2.1 made it worked

Answer (score 1):

DataTable is a jQuery plugin so you need to make sure you are also including jQuery on your page. jQuery will need to be included before you include DataTables. Then to initialize DataTables, you'll need to use `$('<table selector>').DataTable()`, making sure to insert the real selector for your table.

Comment: The jquery is already included. version 2.1.4. Also i have tried setting the table. I get the same error that DataTables() isnt defined.

Comment: You need to use DataTable(), not DataTables()

Comment: i have used datatable and datatables both , no effect on element and it says its not defined , if the datatable is available it should be viewed from browser console just by calling that function